# HttpClient.PostAsync takes twice as long as actual latency?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

This is a windows form application. I am using stop watch to measure the time of this operation:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(EndPoint, stringContent);
```

It comes out to be 600-700 ms. The latency to the web service is ~250 ms. I checked with fiddler and the request is taking <300 ms. So my question is why is there an extra 300-400 ms?

Comment: Are you using measurements from the *same* request (not different requests to the same API, but actually the same network packets)? Have you executed the same code in a loop and averaged the results?

Comment: Actually this API request is inside a timer tick (intervel=500). The latency is displayed at status bar of app. A friend is suggesting that PostAsync method is causing the delay. Is it possible?

Comment: If you mean that the answers to my questions are "no" and "no", then I recommend that you do that kind of testing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the round-trip into account. Your code has 2 parts:

- Sending the request, sent from you to the web service.
- Reading the response, sent from the web service to you.

So your request is still taking ~300ms, but so is the response and that's why the whole thing is taking about 2x your latency.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The overall elapsed column in fiddler shows ~300 ms. Overall elapsed starts from ClientConnected to ClientDoneResponse.